# Deleting array of structures, changing structure adress

Tags: c++, arrays, structure

I create dynamically two arrays of structures (player1 and player1temp). Than i want to make some calculation using data from player1 and save it to player1temp. Then i want to copy data from array player1temp to player1.
Is it a good solution?

```
struct team
{
    int value1;
    int value2;
};


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    team *player1=new team[5];
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        player1[i].value1=rand()%20;
        player1[i].value2=rand()%20;
        cout<<"Player1 index: "<<i<<"     "<<player1[i].value1<<"     "<<player1[i].value2<<"\n";
    }
    team *player1temp=new team[5];
    cout<<"\n\n";
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        player1temp[i].value1=rand()%20;
        player1temp[i].value2=rand()%20;
        cout<<"Player1temp index: "<<i<<"     "<<player1temp[i].value1<<"     "<<player1temp[i].value2<<"\n";
    }
    delete player1;
    player1=player1temp;
    cout<<"\n\n";
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Player1 index: "<<i<<"     "<<player1[i].value1<<"     "<<player1[i].value2<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't deal with raw pointers yourself. Use appropriate [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) or [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) instead.

Comment: It sounds like your code works, but you're unsure of your solution. This would probably be better served on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: C++ has not had structures since 1985.

Answer (score 0):

Two errors:
`delete` should be `delete[]` if used for arrays.
The remaining array should be deleted too before the program ends.

A vector would be easier:

```
struct team
{
    int value1;
    int value2;
};


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    std::vector<team> player1(5);

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        player1[i].value1=rand()%20;
        player1[i].value2=rand()%20;
        cout<<"Player1 index: "<<i<<"     "<<player1[i].value1<<"     "<<player1[i].value2<<"\n";
    }

    std::vector<team> player1temp = player1;

    cout<<"\n\n";
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        player1temp[i].value1=rand()%20;
        player1temp[i].value2=rand()%20;
        cout<<"Player1temp index: "<<i<<"     "<<player1temp[i].value1<<"     "<<player1temp[i].value2<<"\n";
    }

    player1 = std::move(player1temp);
    //don´t use player1temp anymore now

    cout<<"\n\n";
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Player1 index: "<<i<<"     "<<player1[i].value1<<"     "<<player1[i].value2<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it a good solution to use memcpy() function? To copy data from player1temp to player1?

Comment: With a vector? No, it´s completely wrong. With raw pointers, if you fix the two mentioned errors, it´s ok that way (memcpy isn´t necessary for assigning *pointers*)

Comment: Even if you insist on memcpy-like solutions, at least prefer std::copy. This is not C!

Comment: copy(player1,player1+(5*sizeof(team)),player1temp); is it good?

Comment: No. And with a vector, like shown above, a `=` is sufficient. (the "move" is just for saving a bit memory, else both vectors would be stored until the program ends)

Comment: And your edited comment is still wrong (at least for vectors)

Comment: I want to make it without using a vectors

Comment: I'm not familiar with vectors, i want to use solution that i know a bit :D

Comment: @A.Kwas Two things: 1) Vector isn't that hard. As you can see from above, virtually nothing changes with respect to element access. It also copies itself, resizes itself, cleans up after itself, and generally makes your life easier. Not using it is not as bad as turning left and walking around the world to see your buddy who lives one house to the right, but it's close. 2) [If you don't attempt new things, you won't learn anything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Eggs_and_Ham).